# HTML/CSS: Keep Hover-Over Pop Up Boxes In Place Until Something Else is Hovered Over

Tags: html, css

looking for html code to keep a hover-over pop up box in place on a image-map until another part of the image map has been hovered over

as per example, check out my code below - you can see that when you scroll over a country, a pop-up box appears with information about a musician from that country; and what i'm looking for is something to keep that box in place until another country has been hovered over, using only html.

thanks

HTML

```
<body>

<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
<div class="americassoundmap" id="americassoundmap"> 
<div class="americassoundmap_image" id="americassoundmap_image">    
  <img src="http://41.media.tumblr.com/d8e8b561f67d2a68c2675b6e1baadb5f/tumblr_no76qlm55E1tyc2lxo1_1280.png" alt="americassoundmap_map" usemap="#americassoundmap_map">



  <!--start map-->
  <map name="americassoundmap_map">

    <!--start america-->
    <span class="drop_america">
      <span><!-- unnested unnamed span -->
        <div class="america_drop" id="america_drop">
          <area shape="rect" coords="251,195,526,320" alt="america">

                <!--begin john williams-->

          <a href="./williams.php">
            <img src="http://www.jw-collection.de/images/jw9.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>
          </a>
              <iframe width="145" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gT_DXHYPy4I" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          <!-- begin biotext john_williams -->
            <div class="biotext_john_williams" id="biotext_john_williams">
                <br/><h4><center>John Williams: Overture to <i>The Cowboys</i></center></h4>
            </div>
          <!-- end .biotext-john_williams -->

                <!--end john williams-->

                <!--begin leonard bernstein-->

          <a href="./bernstein.php">
            <img src="http://a5.files.biography.com/image/upload/c_fill,cs_srgb,dpr_1.0,g_face,h_300,q_80,w_300/mte4mdazndewndu0mdg3mtgy.jpg"
            width="100" height="100"/>
          </a>
               <iframe width="145" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9tjsKzhpSwE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          <!--begin biotext leonard_bernstein-->
            <div class="biotext_leonard_bernstein" id="biotext_leonard_bernstein">
                <br/><h4><center>Bernstein: Three Meditations from <i>Mass</i></center></h4>
            </div>
          <!--end buotext leonard_bernstein>

                <!--end leonard bernstein-->

        </div><!-- end .america_drop -->
      </span><!-- end unnested unnamed span -->
    </span><!-- end .drop_america -->
    <!-- end america -->

    <!--start mexico-->
    <span class="drop_mexico" title="mexico_drop">
      <span><!--unnested unnamed span-->
        <div class="mexico_drop" id="mexico_drop">
            <area shape="rect" coords="296,300,530,435" alt="mexico">

                <!--begin jose pablo moncayo-->
          <a href="./moncayo.php">
              <img src="http://noticias.starmedia.com/imagenes/2013/06/moncayo-300x300.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>
          </a>
                <iframe width="145" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5HAmrz3-ehI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          <!--begin biotext jose_pablo_moncayo-->
            <div class="biotext_jose_pablo_moncayo" id="biotext_jose_pablo_moncayo">
                <br/><h4><center>Moncayo: <i>Huapango</i></center></h4>
            </div>
          <!--end biotext jose_pablo_moncayo-->
                <!--end jose pablo moncayo-->
        </div>
      </span>
    </span>
    <!--end mexico-->

    <!--start canada-->
  <span class="drop_canada" title="canada_drop">
      <span><!-- unnested unnamed span -->
        <div class="canada_drop" id="canada_drop">
          <area shape="rect" coords="165,75,620,205" alt="canada">
          <a href="./kulesha.php">
            <img src="http://www.kulesha.com/DSC_0139a.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>
            <iframe width="145" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3cBgQsvPSnk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </a>
          <!-- begin biotext gary_kulesha -->
          <div class="biotext_gary_kulesha" id="biotext_gary_kulesha">
            <br/><h4><center>Gary Kulesha: <i>Torque</i></center></h4>
          </div>
          <!-- end biotext gary_kulesha -->
        </div><!-- end .canada_drop -->
      </span><!-- end unnested unnamed span -->
    </span><!-- end .drop_canada -->
    <!--end canada-->

    <!--start argentina-->
    <span class="drop_argentina" title="argentina_drop">
      <span><!-- unnested unnamed span -->
        <div class="argentina_drop" id="argentina_drop">
          <area shape="rect" coords="555,640,625,835" alt="argentina">
          <a href="./piazzola.php">
            <img src="http://www.longbeachopera.org/uploads/images/2012/astor-piazzolla-400-400.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>
            <iframe width="145" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/H_-cfWEMDrU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </a>
          <!-- begin biotext astor piazzola -->
          <div class="biotext_astor_piazzola" id="biotext_astor_piazzola">
            <br/><h4><center>Piazzola: <i>Libertango</i></center></h4>
          </div>
          <!-- end .biotext-aastor_piazzola -->
        </div><!-- end .argentina_drop -->
      </span><!-- end unnested unnamed span -->
    </span><!-- end .drop_argentina -->
    <!-- end argentina -->


  </map>
  <!-- end map -->

  </div>
  <!-- end .americassoundmap_image -->
  </div>
  <!-- end .americassoundmap -->
  </div>
  <!-- end .wrapper -->
  </body>
```

CSS

```
  /*/CSS TEXT FILE FOR MAP/*/

  body {
  line-height: .15em;
}
h1{
font-size: 2em;
}
h2{ 
font-size: 1em;
}
h3{
font-size: .9em;
}
h4{
font-size: .7em;
}
h5{
font-size: .5em;
}
h6{
font-size: .45em;
}

/*BEGIN AMERICA*/

span.drop_america {
border-bottom: thin-solid;
background: #ffeedd;
}
span.drop_america:hover {
text-decoration: none;
background: #ffffff;
z-index: 1;
}
span.drop_america span {
position: absolute;
left: -9999em;
margin: .2em 0 0 0em;
padding: .1em .1em .1em .1em;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: .1em;
z-index: 1;
}
span.drop_america:hover span {
left: 2%;
background: #ffffff;
} 
span.drop_america span {
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
margin: .1em 0em 0em 0em;
padding: .1em .1em .1em .1em;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: .1em;
}
span.drop_america:hover span {
margin: .2em 0 0 .5em;
background: #ffffff;
z-index: 1;
}

/*END AMERICA*/

/*BEGIN MEXICO*/

span.drop_mexico {
border-bottom: thin-solid;
background: #ffeedd;
}
span.drop_mexico:hover {
text-decoration: none;
background: #ffffff;
z-index: 2;
}
span.drop_mexico span {
position: absolute;
left: -9999em;
margin: .2em 0 0 0em;
padding: .1em .1em .1em .1em;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: .1em;
z-index: 2;
}
span.drop_mexico:hover span {
left: 2%;
background: #ffffff;
} 
span.drop_mexico span {
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
margin: .1em 0em 0em 0em;
padding: .1em .1em .1em .1em;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: .1em;
}
span.drop_mexico:hover span {
margin: .2em 0 0 .5em;
background: #ffffff;
z-index: 2;
}

/*END MEXICO*/

/*BEGIN CANADA*/

span.drop_canada {
border-bottom: thin-solid;
background: #ffeedd;
}
span.drop_canada:hover {
text-decoration: none;
background: #ffffff;
z-index: 3;
}
span.drop_canada span {
position: absolute;
left: -9999em;
margin: .2em 0 0 0em;
padding: .1em .1em .1em .1em;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: 1em;
z-index: 3;
}
span.drop_canada:hover span {
left: 2%;
background: #ffffff;
} 
span.drop_canada span {
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
margin: .1em 0em 0em 0em;
padding: .1em .1em .1em .1em;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: .1em;
}
span.drop_canada:hover span {
margin: .2em 0 0 .5em;
background: #ffffff;
z-index: 3;
}

/*END CANADA*/

/*BEGIN ARGENTINA*/

span.drop_argentina {
border-bottom: thin-solid;
background: #ffeedd;
}
span.drop_argentina:hover {
text-decoration: none;
background: #ffffff;
z-index: 4;
}
span.drop_argentina span {
position: absolute;
left: -9999em;
margin: .2em 0 0 0em;
padding: .1em .1em .1em .1em;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: 1em;
z-index: 4;
}
span.drop_argentina:hover span {
left: 2%;
background: #ffffff;
} 
span.drop_argentina span {
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
margin: .1em 0em 0em 0em;
padding: .1em .1em .1em .1em;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: .1em;
}
span.drop_argentina:hover span {
margin: .2em 0 0 .5em;
background: #ffffff;
z-index: 4;
}

/*END ARGENTINA*/
```

Comment: CSS doesn't know a separate mouseenter/ mouseout method like Javascript. So, when hovering off the item, the hover properties will be removed as well. What you would like is not possible with pure CSS. You definitely need Javascript (or jQuery) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use onMouseOver (javascript) to close all pop-up boxes and then open the current one.

The effect will be that the last box stays open until the next one is activated.

Comment: is there no way to do with without javascript... i am already aware of this method.

Comment: You can't do it with just css.  You need javascript.